# How to enforce Azure App Service plan tier using a policy

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-policy

I am fairly new to Azure and I am working on using policies to enforce governance. I have put together this policy definition:

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "not": {
        "field": "kind",
        "in": "[parameters('allowedSKUs')]"
      }
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "allowedSKUs": {
      "type": "Array",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Allowed Storage SKU",
        "description": "The list of allowed skus for resources.",
        "strongType": "storageSkus"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am hoping to be able to enforce the "F1" pricing tier for all App Service plans created in the assigned subscription but it seems it only makes "storage options" available to me when assigning this policy. How do I enforce this using an Azure Policy definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this one:

```json
{
  "mode": "Indexed",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms"
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/sku.name",
            "in": "[parameters('listOfAllowedSKUs')]"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "Deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "listOfAllowedSKUs": {
      "type": "Array",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Allowed SKUs",
        "description": "The list of SKUs that can be specified"
      },
      "defaultValue": ["F1"]
    }
  }
}
```

I was not able to find a strong type for app SKUs.